# Update infor for new field in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

My table contains the following rows
icao, name, country ...

I just added the row "code", so that it now looks like this:
icao, name, country, code ...

I now have a file with all the codes that i want to use for each icao like this:

```
XSXX:SE
XXSS:SE
XXXX:UK
SSSS:LE
```

The icao is a unique entery so there is no duplicate icao's.

Any ideas?

Comment: Plenty of ideas, but no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Read your question and you'll realize that, well, it is not a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `update` with `join`.  First, import the "file" into a table with two columns, `icao` and `code` using the colon as a separator.  Then do:

```
update t join
       file f
       on t.icao = f.icao
    set t.code = f.code;
```

If you import the file with just one character column, you can still do this as:

```
update t join
       file f
       on t.icao = left(f.CharColumn, locate(':', CharColumn) - 1
    set t.code = substr(f.CharColumn, locate(':', CharColumn) + 1);
```